# Flex, Putting SQLite result into a ItemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, flexbuilder

Using the following SQLite statement:

> SELECT Customer, SUM(OrderAmount) AS TotalOrder FROM OrdersTable GROUP BY Customer

I get the result of total sum (total order) of each customer

How can I put the above result into a itemRenderer label.text ?

```
<s:ItemRenderer>
   <s:Label id="customerName" text=??? />
   <s:Label id="totalOrder" text=??? />
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever we set data to a dataprovider it automatically set to its item renderer,
if you are using custom itemrendere then do this...

```
[Bindable] private var _customerName:String;
[Bindable] private var _totalOrder:String;

override public function set data(value:Object):void{
  this.data = value;
  _customerName = value. property   //propertyName containing customer name
  _totalOrder = value. property   //propertyName containing totalOrder
}

   <s:Label id="customerName" text="{_customerName}" /> 
   <s:Label id="totalOrder" text="{_totalOrder}" />
```

or

```
<s:ItemRenderer>    
   <s:Label id="customerName" text="{data.properyNamecontainCustomerName}" />    
   <s:Label id="totalOrder" text="={data.properyNamecontaintotalOrder} " />    
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: missed it... by that much :) Good answer!

Comment: Never do bindings within ItemRenderers. It is considered as being bad practice. It can cause performance issues and in the worst case, memory leaks. Therefore you should always override the `set data` function.

Comment: @DennisJaamann interesting, i don't know that using binding within IR is a bad practice as a lot of books/websites use it. nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

`ItemRenderer`'s have a `data` property which the Flex List control sets on each renderer. You can bind the `text` property of a `Label` to the data, override the setter for the data property, or add an event listener for the "dataChange" event.

When binding you can use curly brace expressions like this:

```
<s:Label text="{data.customerName}" />
```

This assumes that the data provider for your `List` is populated w/an object that has the property `customerName` ;)

The other two approaches require that you write some code that sets the label's text property.

You can find many examples of using a Flex `ItemRenderer`, such as these:

- [Adobe Flex 4.6 * Define a custom Spark item renderer](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=itemrenderer%20example&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html&ei=JHCGT7niN6eyiQLk4aDlDw&usg=AFQjCNHaheynuV7Z6HLykiprHcj4nTwEZg)
- [CoolItemRenderers Made Easy in Flex 4](http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/01/cool-itemrenderers-made-easy-in-flex-4/)
- [Spark List Component Example with inline Item Renderer Flex 4](http://www.flexstreamer.com/?p=165)